# Wanting to update an Adobe CS dropdown list from my google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, adobe

Here is what I wrote for my Google Form to pull data from my Gsheet. But want to pull the same information from the gsheet to an Adobe PDF? Is that even possible. I wanted to use it to make a drop down where it pulls names from a gsheet.

```
var ssID = "enter ssID";
var formID = "enter form ID ";


var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("data");
var form = FormApp.openById(formID);

function main(){
  var labels = wsData.getRange(1, 1,1,wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  
  labels.forEach(function(label,i){
   
    var options = wsData
                  .getRange(2, i + 1,wsData.getLastRow()-1,1)
                  .getValues()
                  .map(function(o){ return o[0] });
    updateDropDownUsingTitle(label,options)
    
    
  });
  
}

function updateDropDownUsingTitle(title,values) {
  
  
  var items = form.getItems();
  var titles = items.map(function(item){
    return item.getTitle();
  });
  
  var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
  var item = items[pos];
  var itemID = item.getId();
  
  
  updateDropdown(itemID,values);
}


function updateDropdown(id, values) {

  var item = form.getItemById(id);
  item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);

}
```

Comment: Creating a PDF from google form/sheets it's quite easy if you create a [template using google docs](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/samples/mail-merge). But I don't know if that is your ultimate goal? What do you mean by the dropdown list? Would you like to see the dropdown in the PDF?

Comment: So I have a google sheet where I update names for certain departments which those names change on a weekly basis. I want to be able to, when I update the gsheet, it then updates the dropdown in an adobe form(to select said person). I have the script in my google form where it does it and works great. But now I would like to see the same thing happen in the adobe form.